# pygame not being imported

Tags: python, pygame

I have a really basic question, pygame isn't being recognized in Windows 7. I have ActiveState Python 2.7 and  pygame-1.9.2a0.win32-py2.7.msi installed. However, a simple hello world program that imports pygame gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "foo.py", line 1, in <module>
import pygame
ImportError: No module named pygame
```

Can anyone help me with this? I am not really familiar with editing the PATH if that is what is needed, thanks.

EDIT: Is it because ActiveState is 64 bit and I'm using the 32 bit version of pygame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, never mind, it appears I needed both versions of ActiveState and pygame to be 32 bit. Works now.

Answer (score 0):

Adding pygame to the path is the first thing I would try.

A really simple (and probably bad to leave it there but okay to test) way to get things running is to locate where your pygame is installed, and add it to sys.path

There is more info here: http://greeennotebook.com/2010/06/how-to-change-pythonpath-in-windows-and-ubuntu/

You can eventually add it to the windows PATH.

Comment: I'll be honest, that is a hard to understand document. Not really clear.

Comment: (Control Panel -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Environmental Variables). First, look for PYTHONPATH. It’s probably not in there unless you’ve already done this. So click on New, and type PYTHONPATH. Now enter the directory(s) you want to add. Make sure to use the forward-slash format Windows likes (C:\Users\Public\Programs), place a semicolon between directories if you add more than one, do not leave spaces between entries, and do not place a semicolon after the last directory on the list! When you’re finished, your directory will be ADDED to your PYTHONPATH.

Comment: btw, i agree that the link was not to the point, so i just extracted the relevant stuff out for you.